# asp.net form behaves different on iPhone

Tags: iphone, asp.net, safari, webforms

A really odd issue..

If I load this page on any browser (safari, ff, ie) on my Win 7 PC:
and select number from the dropdown list & add to cart it works fine
http://culinary-festival.thisticket.com/mobile/EventTime/38.aspx
I see that tickets are added to my cart.

But if I do this on an iphone it does not add any to the cart.

It's the same code, is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: FYI it just worked using my iPad (iOS 5.0.1)

Comment: One of my developers just tested it on his iPhone without any issues too. I turned my phone off and on again and re-tested. My issue persists.

Comment: Are you running the same (or newer) iOS version as your developer? (Settings->General->About)

Comment: cookies were blocked :) solved!